Advice on installing bathtub drain stopper with sealant on the pipe surface
How would you install a drain stopper on this where I can't seem to find the inner threads? The gray rough surface around drain pipe seems like pro dope (sealant).
Should I try scratching the sealant on the inner surface of the drain pipe? I'm not sure if it will damage anything.
The bathtub is installed on the ground slab, so there is no access under it unless the entire tub is removed.
Appreciate any advice on this.



find matching rubber ring

Are you sure that's a threaded component? I think I'd go old-school and get a rubber plug to fit. It doesn't seem worth the risk of causing a leak.

That looks like there is decades of hard water build up on the drain.
Try soaking a towel in CLR  or something similar and stuffing it in the drain to dissolve most of the minerals and stuff.
Then you may be able to see if there are threads left.   If not you can access the drain through the wall on the drain side of the tub. A new tub drain assembly may be needed.
You will need to do a wall repair after, but it is better than removing the tub and everything involved with that.
